# How to search for a string case-insensitively without regular expressions?

Tags: python

I want to search a file for all lines containing a given string without matching case.  How can I make this code case-insensitive?

```py
with open(logfile) as inf:
    for line in inf:
        if var in line:
            print 'found',line
```

Comment: I would go for `fin` instead of `inf` which looks like infinite as used in `float('inf')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
with open(logfile) as fin:
    for line in fin:
        if var.lower() in line.lower():  # makes this case insensitive
            print 'found', line.rstrip() # You will be printing double new lines 
                                         #  without rstrip here
```